# How would I align my mathematical equations vertically along a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, vertical-alignment

I'm looking for a type of environment that would align the equations vertically with any geometric figure, like in the following example/figure:

[image]

Here is my code for the equations:

```
\begin{align*}
&\text{1. }\sin \varphi=\frac{opp}{hyp}
&&\text{4. }\csc \varphi=\frac{h y p}{o p p}
\\\\
&\text{2. }\cos \varphi=\frac{a d j}{hyp}
&&\text{5. }\sec \varphi=\frac{h y p}{a d j}
\\\\
&\text{3. }\tan \varphi=\frac{o p p}{a d j}
&&\text{6. }\cot \varphi=\frac{a d j}{o p p}
\end{align*}
```

Also, my code for the figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;
        
        \coordinate[label=left:$P$](P)  at  (0,0);
        \coordinate[label=right:$Q$](Q)  at  (3,0);
        \coordinate[label=above:$R$](R)  at   (3,2);
        
        \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](P,Q){$x$}
        \tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](Q,R){$y$} 
        \tkzLabelSegment[above left=-2pt](P,R){$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}
        
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](P,R,Q)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](Q,P,R){$\varphi$}
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8](Q,P,R)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](P,R,Q){$\psi$}
        \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,Q,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, next time add the necessary packages. I was lucky to guess `tkz-euclide`, but avoid people having to guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `aligned` for the equations and the `baseline` option to vertically center the picture.

I used a trick to push both parts one em to the margin (because `\hfill` wouldn't work). You can instead just say something like `\hspace{4em}` between the two parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{1. }\sin \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{opp}}{\mathrm{hyp}}
&&\text{4. }\csc \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{hyp}}{\mathrm{opp}}
\\[2ex]
&\text{2. }\cos \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{adj}}{\mathrm{hyp}}
&&\text{5. }\sec \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{hyp}}{\mathrm{adj}}
\\[2ex]
&\text{3. }\tan \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{opp}}{\mathrm{adj}}
&&\text{6. }\cot \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{adj}}{\mathrm{opp}}
\end{aligned}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \draw[very thin] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;

  \coordinate[label=left:$P$](P)  at  (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=right:$Q$](Q)  at  (3,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:$R$](R)  at   (3,2);

  \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](P,Q){$x$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](Q,R){$y$} 
  \tkzLabelSegment[above left=-2pt](P,R){$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}

  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](P,R,Q)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](Q,P,R){$\varphi$}
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8](Q,P,R)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](P,R,Q){$\psi$}
  \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,Q,R)
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you may want to use a `figure` floating environment. In this case you need a caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\hspace{1em}
$\begin{aligned}
&\text{1. }\sin \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{opp}}{\mathrm{hyp}}
&&\text{4. }\csc \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{hyp}}{\mathrm{opp}}
\\[2ex]
&\text{2. }\cos \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{adj}}{\mathrm{hyp}}
&&\text{5. }\sec \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{hyp}}{\mathrm{adj}}
\\[2ex]
&\text{3. }\tan \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{opp}}{\mathrm{adj}}
&&\text{6. }\cot \varphi=\frac{\mathrm{adj}}{\mathrm{opp}}
\end{aligned}$\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
  \draw[very thin] (0,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;

  \coordinate[label=left:$P$](P)  at  (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=right:$Q$](Q)  at  (3,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:$R$](R)  at   (3,2);

  \tkzLabelSegment[below=2pt](P,Q){$x$}
  \tkzLabelSegment[right=2pt](Q,R){$y$} 
  \tkzLabelSegment[above left=-2pt](P,R){$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}

  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7](P,R,Q)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](Q,P,R){$\varphi$}
  \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8](Q,P,R)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](P,R,Q){$\psi$}
  \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,Q,R)
\end{tikzpicture}\quad

\caption{Definition of the trigonometric functions for acute angles}

\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use two minipage environments, side-by-side, as explained in Part V of "Using Imported Graphics in LATEX and pdfLATEX" by Keith Reckdahl, available at CTAN (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/epslatex/english?lang=en).